# Adding apps in the unlock screen

Tags: lock-screens, home-screen-shortcuts

I have a Samsung tablet (not sure of model), running Android 4.0.4.

When I unlock my screen, I have four default options that I can choose from, or I can use the empty area to unlock the main screen. How can I add apps like my favorite games to this menu so I can go directly into those games?

If you need more information, please let me know. Please provide steps for getting the information also.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Go Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jiubang.goscreenlock). It provides you with custom lock screens that can be themed. Cant remember if compatible with tablets though.